# WebRTC Grandstream UCM6510

Tags: ip, nat, sip, webrtc, turn

Some times the webrtc transport connection is stablished but when I observe in chrome://webrtc-internals the dtls session in that transport it stays stucked in “connecting“ and the remote certificate peer from the grandstream never arrives , what can it be ?, and how can I debug it ?

Turn server is configured for clients and the grandstream has a dedicated public ip

Clients are using sip.js library

The TURN server was tested against trickle ice and other several tests and is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone going through the same problem, be sure that if you get this situation you force TCP Turn mode with query param '?transport=tcp' if you're using coturn, in our case for some clients their ISP stock default configuration of the router firewall and IDS system were the responsible of blocking the connections